# Como fazer referencia de uma arrayList de outra classe

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Pessoal meu codigo ainda esta inacabado e estou criando um sistema de biblioteca como trabalho da faculdade quero fazer como uma referencia para utilizar uma array liste de outra classe em uma nova classe. Quero utilizar a mesma arrayList da classe Livro para a classe EmprestimoDeLivro. Fiz instanciando com os mesmos nomes mais nao sei se esta certo pois nunca utilizei este modo. Obrigado
Vou postar apenas o nome da array da classe livro: public ArrayList livros = new ArrayList<>();

Classe EmprestimoDeLivro

```
public class EmprestimoDeLivros {
public String status1 = "Disponivel";
public String status2 = "Emprestado";
public int escolhaDoLivro;

static int escolha;

static Scanner escolhaInput = new Scanner(System.in);
// leitores
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public ArrayList<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<Leitor> leitores = new ArrayList<>();

public static void menuEmprestimo() {
    System.out.println("1- Emprestar um livro.");
    System.out.println("2- Devolver umlivro.");
    System.out.println("3- Menu Principal");
    System.out.println("0- Sair");

    System.out.println("> Entre com sua opcao aqui: ");
    escolha = escolhaInput.nextInt();// Entrada da escolha).
}

public void emprestaLivro() {
    System.out
            .println("---------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out
            .println("> Aqui estao todos os livros registrados na biblioteca: ");
    System.out
            .println("---------------------------------------------------------");

    // Adicionar Funcao que ira chamar a lista de livros a exibir

    while (escolha == 3) {
        laco1: while (escolha == 1) {
            System.out
                    .println("\n\n> Escolha um livro da lista e digite seu numero para escolhe-lo: ");
            escolhaDoLivro = escolhaInput.nextInt() - 1;// Registro do livro
            if (escolhaDoLivro > livros.size()) {
                System.out
                        .println("> O numero do livro que você digitou nao existe!");
                escolha = 3;
            } else if (escolhaDoLivro <= livros.size()) {
                break laco1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem seu exemplo, mas geralmente para se pegar qualquer variável de outra classe você utiliza de algum método ou se o atributo for publico você pode chama-lo diretamente.

A classe abaixo contém uma lista de livros.

```
public class GerenciadorDeLivros {
    public ArrayList<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Livro> getLivros() {
        return livros;
    }

}
```

Note que ele tem um método que só seria "obrigatório"(nesse caso) se o ArrayList não estivesse como público.

Na classe abaixo ele exige que você dê a classe uma lista.

```
public class EmprestimoDeLivro {
    public ArrayList<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();

    public EmprestimoDeLivro(ArrayList<Livro> livros) {
        this.livros = livros;
    }       
}
```

Agora pode usar a vontade

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        GerenciadorDeLivros gerenciador = new GerenciadorDeLivros();
        EmprestimoDeLivro emprestimo = new EmprestimoDeLivro(gerenciador.livros);
    }
```

Obs.: vale ressaltar que você também pode obrigar a receber outra classe, como a classe que gerencia a lista.

```
public class EmprestimoDeLivro {
    public GerenciadorDeLivros gerenciador;

    public EmprestimoDeLivro(GerenciadorDeLivros gerenciador) {
        this.gerenciador = gerenciador;
    }

    public void operacaoComALista(){
        gerenciador.livros.add(new Livro());
        //Outras Operações...
    }
}
```

E o novo main fica assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GerenciadorDeLivros gerenciador = new GerenciadorDeLivros();
    EmprestimoDeLivro emprestimo = new EmprestimoDeLivro(gerenciador);
}
```

Comment: gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789). Acredito que possa ajudar no entendimento da sua resposta.